# Play 2 framework stop server

Tags: windows, windows-7, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am starting my Play 2.0.4 project using the play console and

```
~run
```

It then displays

```
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

However, when pressing Ctrl+D nothing happens, the server does not stop. I am on Windows 7. Any workaround for this except for stopping the complete play console / cmd.exe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is waiting for the End-of-file character. On Unix terminals this is inserted by typing Ctrl-D. On Windows, Ctrl-Z should work.
Although I have experienced situations where it didn't.

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 `ctrl`+`D` works for me for `run` command (without tilda). For `~run` as I can see works combination: (`ctrl`+`D`) + `Enter`

Comment: I noted that "hold ctrl, then press z followed by d " really doesn't work always. now testing just "run", there ctrl+d really works and I think it does the same like ~run, even though it should be different. Thanks biesior, nice hint :-)

Answer (score 0):

Press Enter right after Ctrl-D